# postgres rds large difference between database size on disk and actual tables size

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I am encountering a weird scenario where when I do the following query:

```
SELECT
    pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('MY_DB')) AS total_database_size;
```

I get 459GB , but when I query the individual size of the indexes and the tables I only get a fraction of the size, the sum of the query below is than 10GB.
Using this query:

```
SELECT nspname || '.' || relname AS "relation",
    pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(C.oid)) AS "size"
  FROM pg_class C
  LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace)
  WHERE nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
  ORDER BY pg_relation_size(C.oid) DESC;
```

I tried to `vacuum analyse` and it didn't help.

Why my storage is so bloated ?

Additional information the might help:

1. I am using DBT, it does create temporary tables but it wasn't running so I don't think it had any affect
2. I am importing data using Fivetran.

Comment: The only explanation I can think of is that your database crashed during `VACUUM (FULL)` or a data load, and some orphaned files stayed behind.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe is it possible that 7GB turned to 459 DB ?? or are these temporary files created that are suddenly not clearable ?

Comment: They get cleared if the statement fails with an error, but not if there is a crash. To reach 459GB that would have to happen several times...